# Iterm2 Text Stacking on Itself

Tags: terminal, iterm, preferences, text-editor

I cannot figure out how to fix my iterm2 window. The text is simply overlapping itself when the window is anything except maxed out:

[image: overlapped text editor]

Of course, I can't use iterm2 like this, so fixing would be great. I've checked out similar stack exchange questions and other resources with similar problems, but none had the same problem or a solution that fixed this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you switch to another font within iTerm?

Comment: To no avail @nohillside

Comment: aka same problem

Comment: I have the same problem, although this occurs for me in iTerm & Terminal.app, so I'm not sure it's related to iTerm. For me I can easily reproduce by quick producing output in a tmux window while ssh'd. The terminal can't keep up with the speed of the output, and as a result many characters are left rendered as bugged artifacts on the screen, overlapping any new characters. Exiting/detaching tmux leaves the characters there, leading me to believe that this is a terminal rendering bug

Comment: Updating font / terminal themes does not fix the issue